# ASP.Net rewrite rule from one domain to a similar domain

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to write a rewrite rule that will take www.mydomain1.co.uk/* and rewrite to www.mydomain2.co.uk/*

I have the following rule that isn't working as I suspect it gets into a infinite loop.

Can anyone help please

```
    <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^mydomain1\.co\.uk/$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain10.co.uk/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

try once following code

```
          <rule name="Canonical Host Name">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain1\.co\.uk" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain10.co.uk/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```